# showing "p = 0.1" when comparing means in boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am comparing different boxplots with oneanother. The comparisons work fine, but I want to formate it so that instead of just showing the p value it is shown like "p = ....".

this line of code doesnt do the trick
`p + stat_compare_means(comparisons = comparison,method = "t.test", aes(label =paste("p= ",  ..p.format..)))`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `sprintf("p = %s", ..p.format..)` instead of `paste`. Can you give a code example, using, say, built-in data set `iris[c(1, 5)]`?

Comment: Unfortunately 'sprintf("p = %s", ..p.format..)' didnt work. Here is a code example: `data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

p<-ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len", width = 0.8)
my_comp = list(c("0.5","1"),c("2","1"))
p
p+stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comp, aes(label =..p.format..))`
 instead of having just the p value about the "comparison bar" it like it to say: "p = 7e-06"

Comment: It works without the `comparisons` argument. So I believe it's a bug in function `stat_compare_means`. Maybe ask `maintainer("ggpubr")`?

Comment: Just did, thank you for your help!

Comment: did you get a solution for this?